# Can I use Apache, cgi-bin, and Python?

Tags: python, apache, cgi-bin

My question is more theoretical than anything.

What I have:

- Linux machine
- A python script that runs an entire suite of tests.
- The same script prints out all of the information to the terminal.

Currently, the way we run our software suite is via SSH to the machine, running `python3 MyScript.py` and then checking the output.

My goal is to create an interface that would work on a Linux/Windows machine and tablet, and would be able to execute the script, as well as visually display progress of it.

I figured, the best approach (also possibly the easiest?) is to use a web server. Web Interface is fairly universal regardless of platform it is being accessed from. And the backend is as simple as `apt get install apache2` and voila! Done!

However, I have never had experience setting up cgi-bin, etc. My question is: is it actually feasible? Am I able to have an HTML button that when clicked will execute MyScript.py server-side and perhaps even parse through whatever the script is outputting to the terminal. That way I would know exactly what the script is doing, and its progress.

Any help regarding this approach (or technologies I can use) is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A better place to ask questions about setting up servers is ServerFault.com.

Comment: Consider jenkins

Comment: Certainly. Running scripts via [CGI](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html) is considered a little old-fashioned, but for simple tasks like this there's nothing wrong with it, IMHO. You may even be able to do what you want without using the cgi module, although it does have some nice features that are worth investigating. You will need to do some reading to use it properly, but the learning curve is smaller than learning a full-blown Web framework.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, will do!!